# Error with ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bukkit

I'm getting a error with `ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes` since I added a custom config to my plugin.

Here is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.bukkit.ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes(ChatColor.java:206)
 ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1473]
        at com.gmail.santiagoelheroe.LoginVip.<init>(LoginVip.java:44) ~[?:?]
```

The error says the problem is at line 44 inside `LoginVip` class.

```
YamlConfiguration configuracion = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(configFile);
String textpermisos = configuracion.getString("Configuration.NoPermissionsMessage");

// Line 44
String permisos = (ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', textpermisos));

String prefixtext = configuracion.getString("Configuration.Prefix");
String prefix = (ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', prefixtext));
```

I have to fix this error to finish my first plugin.

**Config.class:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration;

public class Config {

    public static File configFile = new File("Plugins/LoginVip/config.yml");

    public static void load() {
        YamlConfiguration spawn = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(configFile);   
    }
    public static void saveConfig() {
        YamlConfiguration configuracion = new YamlConfiguration(); 
        configuracion.set("Configuration.NoPermissionsMessage", "&cYou don't have permissions to do that");
        try {
            configuracion.save(configFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LoginVip.log.log(Level.WARNING, "[LV] Error creating Config.yml file");
        }
    }
 }
```

**onEnable:**

```
@Override

    public void onEnable() {  
    log.log(Level.INFO, "[LV] Plugin loaded");
    if(!Config.configFile.exists()) {
      Config.saveConfig();
    }
    if(!Config.spawnFile.exists()) {
      Config.saveSpawn();
    }
      Config.load();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`textpermisos` is `null`. From the Javadocs of [`MemoryConfiguration.getString(String)`](https://github.com/Wolvereness/Bukkit-Bleeding/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/configuration/MemorySection.java#L278-L282):

> Gets the requested String by path.
>
> If the String does not exist but a default value has been specified, this will return the default value. **If the String does not exist and no default value was specified, this will return null.**

This means that your configuration file does not contain the key-value mapping for "`Configuration.NoPermissionsMessage`". It  is `null`, which is then passed into [`ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes(char, String)`](https://github.com/Wolvereness/Bukkit-Bleeding/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/ChatColor.java#L195-L214). Here is its source code, with a comment of mine indicating which line `ChatColor.java:206` in  your crash log was:

```
/*
 * Translates a string using an alternate color code character into a
 * string that uses the internal ChatColor.COLOR_CODE color code
 * character. The alternate color code character will only be replaced if
 * it is immediately followed by 0-9, A-F, a-f, K-O, k-o, R or r.
 *
 * @param altColorChar The alternate color code character to replace. Ex: &
 * @param textToTranslate Text containing the alternate color code character.
 * @return Text containing the ChatColor.COLOR_CODE color code character.
 */
public static String translateAlternateColorCodes(char altColorChar, String textToTranslate) {
    char[] b = textToTranslate.toCharArray(); // textToTranslate is null, it causes a NPE to be thrown.
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length - 1; i++) {
        if (b[i] == altColorChar && "0123456789AaBbCcDdEeFfKkLlMmNnOoRr".indexOf(b[i+1]) > -1) {
            b[i] = ChatColor.COLOR_CHAR;
            b[i+1] = Character.toLowerCase(b[i+1]);
        }
    }
    return new String(b);
}
```

To solve this:

- Add default mapping so `getString()` would not return `null` but instead a default value. Here is one way to do this (consult the documentation for applying as `HashMap`):

  ```
  YamlConfiguration configuracion = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(configFile);

  String defpermisos = "";
  String textpermisos = configuracion.getString("Configuration.NoPermissionsMessage", defpermisos);
  String permisos = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', textpermisos);

  String defprefix = "";
  String textprefix = configuracion.getString("Configuration.Prefix", defprefix);
  String prefix = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', textprefix);
  ```
- Modify your code to only translate color codes after a `!= null` check.

  ```
  YamlConfiguration configuracion = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(configFile);

  String textpermisos = configuracion.getString("Configuration.NoPermissionsMessage");
  String permisos = null;
  if (textpermisos != null)
      permisos = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', textpermisos);

  String prefixtext = configuracion.getString("Configuration.Prefix");
  String prefix = null;
  if (prefixtext != null)
      prefix = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', prefixtext);
  ```

Comment: I think that is incorrect my file **"Configuration.NoPermissionsMessage"** isn't **Null**... I did update the code so check it .

Comment: @MaTaMoR_ `textpermisos` is `null` because configuration node `Configuration.NoPermissionsMessage` from `YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(configFile)` __Does not exist__ and __no default value is associated__. According to the bukkit specification, "If the String does not exist and no default value was specified, this will return null." This has to do with the config file loading, not your code.

Comment: *configuracion.set("Configuration.NoPermissionsMessage", "&cYou don't have permissions to do that");*

Comment: @MaTaMoR_ Did you _really_ call `saveConfig()` before you load with `getString()`?

Comment: I only use saveConfig() if config file does not exist .

Comment: @MaTaMoR_ You have to call `YamlConfiguration.save(File)` if the variable will be disposed.

Comment: If i remove string *permisos* and *prefix* the config works perfect .

Comment: I quote myself: This has to do with the config file loading, not your code.

Comment: I did put the **OnEnable** config in the post , ¿ you can check it ?